# How to convert a 5 bit binary string to an alphabetic character?

Tags: ruby, encoding

If I have a 5 bit binary string such as `'01010'`, how can I convert it to its corresponding alphabetic character?

(`'00000'`->`'a'` .. `'11111'`->`'F'`)

I am doing this to compress a large set of boolean values to a string which can only contain the alphabetic characters [a-zA-Z].

Comment: In what encoding 0 represents `a`? Or conversion is done in some other way?

Comment: It's a made up encoding. I am numbering the characters [a-zA-Z] 0-31.

Comment: I see. Keep in mind that there're actually 52 characters, not 32.

Comment: 5 bits is only enough for a-zA-F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
letters = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'F').to_a
letters["00000".to_i(2)] # => 'a'
letters["11111".to_i(2)] # => 'F'
letters["01010".to_i(2)] # => 'k'
```

Answer (score 3):

A version for generic charset

```
s = '00001'
code = s.to_i(2)
puts (?a.ord + code).chr  # => b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for encoding and decoding the boolean values, using [LBg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059900/how-to-convert-a-5-bit-binary-string-to-an-alphabetic-character/5059937#5059937):

```
class SomeClass
    @@letters = (('a'..'z').to_a+('A'..'F').to_a)
    def self.decode str
        str.chars.map do |c|
            c = @@letters.index(c).to_s(2)
            while c.length < 5
                c = "0#{c}"
            end
            c
        end.join('').split('').map do |c|
            if c == '1'
                true
            else
                false
            end
        end
    end
    def self.encode *bools
        str = ''
        until bools.length == 0
            five = ''
            5.times do
                five += bools.length > 0 ? (bools.shift() ? '1' : '0') : '0'
            end
            str += @@letters[five.to_i(2)]
        end
        str
    end
end
```

It is OK that I am padding the array of booleans with extra booleans because in my program, I know exactly how many booleans I have so I can truncate the decoded array.

Comment: Rather than add an answer, you could edit your original question. If this is your selected answer then that's OK, mark it as such so the question will show as answered.